# how to increment each row value in round robin method till some extent of given integer

Tags: python, pandas, loops, counter

trying to split an integer value to each row in dataframe

### i have a pandas dataframe with 4 rows and say an integer as 5. the end result should have 2 for the first row and 1 for rest 3 rows.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d'],columns=['name'])
df['val']=0
no=5
while no>0:
    for row in df['val']:
           df['val']= row+1
           no-=1
```

---

'Eventually one count has to be taken from 'no' and added to each row in the dataframe

i need to iterate through rows in a dataframe and increment the cell value till any said integer count.

Expected output

after 1 iteration the df will look like this and no will decrement to 4

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a','b','c','d'],[1,0,0,0])),columns=['name','val'])
```

after 2nd iteration df will be as below and no will decrement to 3

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a','b','c','d'],[1,1,0,0])),columns=['name','val'])
```

and this iteration goes till the any given integer. so for this case 4 th iteration will be as below and and no will decrement to 1

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a','b','c','d'],[1,1,1,1])),columns=['name','val'])
```

and the final 5th iteration will be as below and no will decrement to 0 and loop ends

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a','b','c','d'],[2,1,1,1])),columns=['name','val'])
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: what is row+1 supposed to do? you can't add an integer to a dataset (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the value 1 in each row other than the first one, and [no - (number of non-first rows)] in the first row. You can get that by:

```
df['col'] = 1
df.loc[0, 'col'] = no - (len(df) - 1)
```

It is worth to mention that loops over the rows are almost always to be avoided when working with `pandas`. You can do almost everything without using loops on the rows (and way faster).

EDIT:
This is the best way to achieve what you requested in the edited question, if you have to loop on `no` for some other reason:

```
df['val'] = 0
no = 5
for i in range(no):
    df.iloc[i % len(df), -1] += 1
```

But if you don't really need to loop, and just get the output in `val`, use:

```
df.loc[df.reset_index().index, 'val'] = no // len(df) + 1 * (df.reset_index().index < no % len(df))
```

Comment: Hi Aryerez, the integer value is dynamic and so the given output works only if the value is 5. i have updated the question for better understanding. please have a look once

Comment: the value is adding to only one cell but if i increase the no it should be divided to all rows equally